# Making a block's content's all show in one row

Tags: views, routes, blocks, media, theming

I have a block that is made up of 3 subblocks: an image block, a menu block and a views block.  I combine the three blocks programmatically like this:

```
function inflatable_icons_menu_combo_block_content() {
    $block = block_load('views', 'icon_views-block_5');
    $block2 = block_load('menu', 'menu-facebook-menu');
    $block3 = block_load('imageblock', '1');
    $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block3, $block, $block2))));
    return ($output);
}
```

Now this block shows up with all three blocks and looks like this:

[image]

But I need the image to show up on the same row as the other two blocks.  What would be a good way to make it all show up on one line?

Comment: Do you have a public URL we can look at, or even the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a stylesheet issue. Everything should 'float:left'. If this has already been done, then your first block is too wide and is forcing the other blocks to displace down.

Experiment with maxwidh on your first block to leave room for the other two.